# Accept javascript function with parameters, as a parameter (no wrapper)?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to write this without the surrounding "wrapper" anonymous function() ? 
So, basicly turn `runner(function(){ myfunction('hello world') }, 'Works!!!')` into this `runner(myfunction('hello world'), 'Works!!!')`

**JS**

```
function runner(func, something)
{
    alert(something);
    func();
}


function myfunction(value)
{
    alert("I should execute last!");
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="javascript: runner(function(){ myfunction('hello world') }, 'Works!!!')">Hit me</button>
```

**JS FIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/pST95/

Comment: What you're looking for is [partial application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application). `Function.prototype.bind` can bind parameters, but something like [`_.partial`](http://underscorejs.org/#partial) might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that you can do that after all :-) You can use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to create a new function object, with the first parameter as the current context and rest of the arguments as the arguments to the actual function.

```
function runner(func, something) {
    console.log(something);
    func();
}

function myfunction(value) {
    console.log(value);
    console.log("I should execute last!");
}

runner(myfunction.bind(this, 'hello world'), 'Works!!!')
```

**Output**

```
Works!!!
hello world
I should execute last!
```

Comment: technically the bind call still produces a wrapper function, but at least it's not inline.

Comment: I keep forgetting about those less known functionalities o.O

Comment: @zzzzBov Correct. I mentioned that in my answer also :)

Comment: @thefourtheye It worked with just ".bind", without using "this" :-)

Comment: @BakedInhalf If you don't have to pass any arguments, then `bind` itself is fine :)

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to write this without the surrounding "wrapper" anonymous function()?

To have pre-set parameters you'll need to use a wrapper function one way or another. It's convenient to not need to declare it inline, but all solutions will still require that a wrapper function is used.

The ability to pre-set parameters to a function before it's executed is called ["Partial Application"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application). Basically the concept is that you call a function to generate a new function. The new function will call the original function with the correct parameters.

## Vanilla JavaScript

[`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) allows for additional arguments to be passed after the context which will then be used when the function is eventually called:

```
runner(myfunction.bind(window, 'hello world'), 'Works!!!');
```

Of course, IE8 and below don't support this function, so you'll need to use the polyfill to enable this behavior.

## jQuery

[`$.proxy`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) is the cross-browser compatible version in the jQuery library:

```
runner($.proxy(myfunction, window, 'hello world'), 'Works!!!');
```

## Underscore

[`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) is the cross-browser compatible version in the Underscorejs library:

```
runner(_.bind(myfunction, window, 'hello world'), 'Works!!!');
```

however if you want to avoid binding the context when generating the wrapper, underscore also provides a true partial application function.

[`_.partial`](http://underscorejs.org/#partial) will bind the arguments only and allow the context to be determined when the function is executed:

```
runner(_.partial(myfunction, 'hello world'), 'Works!!!');
```

Answer (score 2):

What you also can do is use apply or call, so that:

```
<button onclick="javascript: runner(myfunction,'hello world', 'Works!!!')">Hit me</button>

function runner(func, args, something)
{
    alert(something);
    func.call(this, args);
}

function myfunction(value)
{
    alert("I should execute last!");
}
```

Comment: Why would you use `call` there, if all you're doing is using a extra parameter? Might as well use `func(args);`

Answer (score 0):

Your `runner` function expects a function that takes no arguments because it runs it like this:

```
func();
```

So you can't really pass `myfunction` to it like this:

```
runner(myfunction, 'Works!!!')
```

Because you don't have a way to give `myfunction` an argument (technically it does actually work because your `myfunction` doesn't use the argument anyway). But if you try this:

```
runner(myfunction('hello world'), 'Works!!!')
```

Then all you are doing is calling `myfunction` directly and sending the returned value (in this case `undefined`) as an argument to `runner` and if you look at the console, you should see an error: `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

So no, you need the wrapper from your original call or you can use `Function.prototype.bind` as thefortheye suggested.

Comment: @Cerbrus: The answer explains why no. Although as *thefourtheye* points out there is a way with `Function.prototype.bind` although it's essentially the same as wrapping it but with a different syntax.

Comment: @Cerbrus you are correct, but this is why I had the wrapper in the first place. Was looking for a way to skip it. Alter "runner" or something similar